# How to create an array of integers from a hexstring in php?

Tags: php, arrays, hex

I can suppose this question has been asked before, but I cannot find any.

I have a string representing hexadecimal values, like

```
$sHex = "314E6B";
```

I want to convert this string as simple/elegant as possible to an array containing the decimal values of these three characters, i.e. an array with the values

```
(49, 78, 107)
```

I looked into `pack`, `hex2dec`, `array_split` but those would include loops I am trying to avoid. A solution with one or two lines  (and no loop) is preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code :

```
$sHex = "314E6B";
$aDec = array_map('hexdec', str_split($sHex, 2));
print_r( $aDec );
```

Will output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 49
    [1] => 78
    [2] => 107
)
```